# Получение данных из диалогового окна PrintDialog C#

Tags: c#, winforms, принтер

Есть ли возможность получить данные из диалогового окна `PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();`
Суть такова, что нужно настроить принтер единоразово и потом многократно обращаться к нему с теми параметрами, что были сохранены в результате настройки, меняя только содержание документа, оставляя все остальное неизменным.
Используемая библиотека `System.Drawing.Printing;`

При попытке получить данные методом `string str = PrinterSettings.ToString();` получаю ошибку требуется ссылка на объект

Comment: Что за класс, из какой библиотеки?

Comment: System.Drawing.Printing

Comment: Так и напишите в вопросе, еще тип приложения в тегах неплохо бы указать.

Comment: `PrinterSettings` - это _свойство_ класса PrintDialog.

Comment: Не понимаю, что-бы не делал получить данные с PrintDialog не получается

Comment: Создали `var printDialog = new PrintDialog();`, показали `printDialog.ShowDialog()`, сохранили настройки в поле `_printerSettings = printDialog.PrinterSettings;`. В следующий раз эти настройки можно сразу назначить `printDialog.PrinterSettings = _printerSettings;`

Comment: Или, как вариант, сам `PrintDialog` сделайте полем формы и используйте один экземпляр на протяжении жизни всего приложения.